# After running unit test, SQLite seems auto cleared but SharedPreferences doesn't. Is it right?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

After running my instrumented unit tests, I found that SQLite data seems auto cleared, but SharedPreferences files still persisted in my device. Am I wrong? In both cases I use the same mock Context to create SQLiteOpenHelper and SharedPreferences.

The simplified code snippet is listed below.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyTest {

    Context mMockContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mMockContext = new RenamingDelegatingContext(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(), "test_");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSQLite() throws Exception {
        MySQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(mMockContext);
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testSharedPreferences() throws Exception {
        SharedPreferences settings = mMockContext.getSharedPreferences("Foo", 0);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, these resources would still be there if you don't manually remove it.

To keep the test isolated from other test, consider clean these resource in either:

```
@AfterClass
public void tearDownClass() { }
```

or:

```
@After
public void tearDown() {}
```